# Longest lasting government

Tags: government

The other week, my political science professor asserted in class that the United States is the longest-running stable government. I brought this up with my philosophy professor though, and he said that Sparta went longer under the laws of Lycurgus.

What is the longest running government in history?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Japan's imperial dynasty is running since 600BC (by Japanese tradition) but certainly for the last 1500 years by clear historical records.

Comment: I guess this depends on how you define 'stable'.

Comment: Switzerland from 1291?  Very much depends on what your professor defines as "stable": after all, the US was divided into two countries in the 1860s, and fought a rather devastating war over that.

Comment: Unfortunately this is quite completely dependent on what is meant by "stable" and "government" and thus largely a matter of opinion. My take on this would echo Pieter's answer that the British government has America beat by over a century, but your professor could well define "stable" in a way to exclude the UK.

Comment: In ancient and medieval eras many realms or states existed for many centuries with relatively little change.  One  could argue that the Roman government lasted from its foundation sometime near the traditional date of 753 BC (HE 9248 until the 4th Crusade in 1204 (HE 11204) or even until 1453 (HE 11453) and thus for about 1,956 or even about 2,205 years, but there is a question about how stable it was for the entire period.

Comment: I can imagine a sign at Buckingham Palace saying something like: "Buckingham Palace Home of the British Monarchy 330 years without a usurpation".

Answer (score 3):

The British have had a stable government [from 1688](https://eh.net/encyclopedia/the-glorious-revolution-of-1688/) ([arguably from the 1660 Restoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restoration_(England))) to the present, a run that predates the [U.S. Constitution ratification in 1788](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Constitution#1788_ratification) by 100 years, As both forms of government continue in tandem, the former has clearly run for a longer extent than the latter.

As both governments are also [Representative Democracies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representative_democracy), the U.S. cannot even claim to be the longest running instance of that governmental form.

Comment: Do you include the collapse of the British Empire in this analysis? If one included this, then the claim looks more dubious. After all, Winston Churchill said he hadn't become the British Prime-minister to see the sun set on her majesty's empire.

Comment: I was going to write an answer about the City of London Corporation, but it was stripped of its rights by Charles II in 1683, and regained them in 1690. Maybe it continued to operate. And... what about the pope?

Comment: The Principality of Monaco (1419-1793) beats this British record:-)

Comment: @MoziburUllah: There was no *British Empire* in either 1688 or 1660. The form of government for the United Kingdom is continuous in all essential ways from then (take your pick of the two dates) to the present.

Comment: @Alex: At 374 years that only beats the United Kingdom by sixteen (1660) or forty four (1688) years. I'm betting on the United Kingdom.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkins: And my bet in on the Japanese empire:-)

Comment: @Alex: The Tokugawa Shogunate is only 1600–1868, for 268 years. Ignoring either the Meiji Restoration or the civil war prior to the Tokugawa shogunate would be akin to saying that British government didn't change through the Cromwell era.

Comment: @Alex: At a modern population of only ~39,000, minuscule compared to ancient Athens at 250,000 to 300,000, Monaco hardly ranks as a "state" regardless of legalities.

Answer (score -2):

China is usually said to be the longest running polity, though of course they have had periods where government broke down, for example during the warring states period and more recently, when Communist China drove the Nationalist forces under Chiang Kai-Shek from the Chinese mainland to Taiwan.

Comment: There were many more periods of discontinuity than you mention.

Comment: @Alex: Sure. Were you expecting me to list them all? I gave two examples, one from China's early history and one from its late history.

Comment: No, I supposed you list a single continuous period of stability which you consider the longest one.

Comment: @Alex: Which is exactly what I did. I named a continuous polity though I wasn't specific about dates. There seemed no need for it given its length. I don't understand your 'No' - and the sentence after that looks confusing. What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: @Alex: Not only were there "discontinuities" (like the Mongols taking over much of the country), for a lot of the time China wasn't even a single country.

Comment: @jamesqf: Sure, but they kept the administrative and governance structure intact.